# How to reach Dam Square from Schiphol airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, amsterdam, ams

I'm going to Amsterdam for the first time. I want to know how to reach Dam Square from Schiphol airport.

Answer (score 7):

Schiphol has a train station, which you will more or less walk into from the arrivals. In the main hall of the airport, go downstairs to get to the platform. Before that, buy a ticket at the yellow machines to *Amsterdam Centraal*.

Trains are departing at a very regular basis. On the website of [the major Dutch train company](http://www.ns.nl/en/travellers/home), you can find all trains leaving there. Pay attention that Schiphol is a regular train station, with trains leaving in several directions. Take the direct connection to "Amsterdam centraal", but not the ones indicated *Fyra*, as the are more expensive.

From there, it is only a [ten minutes walk](https://maps.google.nl/maps?saddr=Amsterdam%20Centraal,%20Burgwallen%20Nieuwe%20Zijde,%20Amsterdam&daddr=Dam%20Square,%20De%20Wallen,%20Amsterdam&hl=en&ll=52.374656,4.898958&spn=0.010716,0.026479&sll=52.375809,4.899044&sspn=0.010715,0.026479&geocode=FUA8HwMdmMZKACnP5YOvtwnGRzGBDJwEgv1n4g;FXIlHwMdwKlKACnvFEs7xwnGRzH5BNqAW7IJmA&t=h&dirflg=w&mra=ltm&z=16) (follow the tram line on either side).

Comment: So nice of U darling thx for Ur Explanation

Comment: Be careful of one thing: if you buy a R/T ticket, it is only good for _that day!_  Not a 24-hour day, that calendar day.  I got zapped for $30 by the conductor.

Comment: Instead of the 10 minute walk to Dam square, you can take a tram (line 1, 2 or 5, 1.60 Euro).

Answer (score 0):

Get a Train from Amsterdam Schiphol Train Station to Amsterdam Central. From Amsterdam Central to Dam square is five to ten minutes walk.

You can get ticket from ticket machines or there is help desk to get details and ticket. (€ 4.20 + €1.00)